# Saving a local data in a JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create two JQuery functions. One of which will use the data created in the other function. Say:

```
jQuery.fn.myScroller = function (child) {
    var $moveable = this.children(child);
    var $children = this.children(child).children();

    posl = posl.replace('px', '');
    post = post.replace('px', '');
    var varList = [];
    $children.each(function () {
        var currVar = {};
        currVar.w = $(this).width();
        varList.push(currVar);
    });
    // I want to save varList variable somehow.
    this.varList = varList; // (1)
};

jQuery.fn.scrollUnitLeft = function () {
    // Now I need to use this varList if this function called
    // But the following returns undefined.
    // However, I've saved it inside this at (1)
    console.log(this.varList)
// More code...
}


$('#main_div').myScroller("#dummydiv");
$('#main_div').scrollUnitLeft();
```

As I explained in comments in the code, this doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly you aren't actually required to have those two jQuery functions. You may use just one, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your jQuery functions, `this` refers to the jQuery object instance used in each case.

In your code you create two jQuery object instances (one for every `$(...)` call), so the data is set in the first instance, and hence not available to the second instance.

If you were to run both your methods on the same jQuery object instance, they would work as expected.

```
jQuery.fn.mySet = function(){
  this.myVar = this.attr('id');
};

jQuery.fn.myGet = function(){
  console.log(this.myVar);
}

$('#a_div').mySet();
$('#a_div').myGet(); // outputs 'undefined'

var $other_div = $('#other_div');
$other_div.mySet();
$other_div.myGet(); // outputs 'other_div'
```

To achieve what you intend, you have to persist the data someplace other than the jQuery object instance. jQuery offers a way to do this via the `.data()` method. This method allows you to attach data to DOM elements. Check its [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

```
jQuery.fn.myRealSet = function(){
  this.data('myVar', this.attr('id'));
};

jQuery.fn.myRealGet = function(){
  console.log(this.data('myVar'));
}

$('#final_div').myRealSet();
$('#final_div').myRealGet(); // outputs 'final_div'
```

You can test this snippets here: http://jsfiddle.net/HPjYn/

**EDIT:** I cannot yet comment on other people's answers, but adding a jQuery prototype varable as suggested will make the data available from any jQuery object instance, which I don't think is what it's intended here.

Comment: You're new here but know how to do. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Creating a namespace or global variable as suggested doesn't look clean to me. You're already extending jQuery, so make it a jQuery variable:

```
jQuery.fn.varList = varList;
```

Edit: I don't really know the jQuery internals. If `fn` is meant to be for functions only, either put it into `jQuery` itself or write a getter

```
jQuery.fn.getVarList = function () {
    return varList;
}
```

Comment: Maybe one thing to watch out for is not to overwrite existing functions. For that a namespace is useful -- I just don't like putting it into the global `window` context. Plus, after all, your functions aren't in a special namespace either.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a namespace at the global scope:

```
window.yourNamespace = {};
```

and then put your `varList` variable in that namespace:

```
yourNamespace.varList = []; //Whatever you want here
```

This way the variable will be available to both of your functions (or any function for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of `this` looks a little buggy to me (pardon me, you may be a lot more experienced than me)! `this` refers to the caller of the function. Both the times it is the div `main_div`. Try using a global variable which is declared outside both the functions or use `data` attribute on the div in the first function, and access that value in the second.